# php uploaded file not visible

Tags: php, upload

After reading the w3schools file (http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) I followed the same steps to upload the image file. However i'm not able to see the file in wampp\tmp folder. Here is my code:

```
<?php
 if($_FILES["file"]["error"] >0 )
 {
  echo "ERROR:" .$_FILES["file"]["error"]. "<br>";
  }
  else
 {
    echo "upload" .$_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "type" .$_FILES["file"]["type"]. "<br>";
    echo "Size" . $_FILES["file"]["size"]."<br>";
    echo "stored in" .$_FILES["file"]["localhost/tom/upload/"]. "<br>";
   }
  ?> <!DOCTYPE html>
      <head>
       <title>Uploading file</title>
      </head>
      <body>
      <form name="f1" action="fup2.php"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="f1" /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="send" />
      </form>
     </body>
      </html>
```

Only sessions are saved in the tmp folder, but not the image..
Please suggest.

Comment: share html code as well, what is the error in backend?

Comment: `["file"]["POPU"]..["file"][".PNG"]..["file"]["835X538"]` none of these elements exist - why did you change these from the example you linked to??

Comment: I just added the image name, type and its size. Is this the correct way or should i paste as it is given in the 3schools example

Comment: You must paste as it was done on the website you give... What you have done is totally wrong. You should keep name, type [...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to move the file from the temp folder to an real one.
Try:

> move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
>         "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

If you like following w3schools they explain it right under where you linked.
("Saving the Uploaded File")

Comment: Do I need to add the new path url in the ["name"] section?

Comment: @THOMAS ["NAME"] Will take the name of the file uploaded. Your new path where to save the file is ...,"upload/"...
change upload to what you want and make sure the folder exist, you may also need to set Read/write permissions on folder.
Also read the comment on your first post by user574632. The ["type"] etc should not be changed. Script will automatically found the right type, size etc..

Comment: hi Darloz, thanks for the help. This is my new path where i need to save the image file localhost/tom/upload/

Comment: Still no change.. File is not getting uploaded. Can u edit the code and send me the correct uploading code?

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I figured it out.

Comment: I'm sorry for not follow up, have been a bit buzzy.
But if the answer was the problem, please mark it as "correct". @THOMAS

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the form has at least the following:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Files can only be sent through `POST`, and the enctype needs to be `multipart/form-data`.

Check the PHP error log if that wasn't the issue.

You can find the location where temporary files are supposed to be saved with `sys_get_temp_dir()`.

Comment: Check the location where the temporary files are uploaded with `sys_get_temp_dir()`